# Pagination does not find the current position

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I recently created a recyclerview with an Api, using retrofit.
I made a paging using OnScrollListener, and it's working. But when I click on some file it does not find the position of it, how can I solve this error?

I looked here in the forum about it and did not find anything related to retrofit. I just want to select the file and send it to another activity, to send the right id.

```html
public class AcervoFragment extends Fragment {
    private Retrofit retrofit;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private AcervoAdaptador acervoAdaptador;
    private ProgressBar progressBar2;
    private List<Lancamentos> listaLancamentos = new ArrayList<>();
    private int pagina;
    private boolean aptoCarregar;

    public AcervoFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_acervo, container, false);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewAcervo);
        acervoAdaptador = new AcervoAdaptador(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(acervoAdaptador);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        final GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("api")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                if (dy > 0) {
                    int visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
                    int totalIntemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
                    int pastVisibleItems = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                    if (aptoCarregar) {
                        if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisibleItems) >= totalIntemCount) {
                            Log.i("TAG", "Carregando");
                            aptoCarregar = false;
                            pagina += 1;
                            obterDados(pagina);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        });
        aptoCarregar = true;
        pagina = 1;
        obterDados(pagina);
        return view;
    }

    public void obterDados(int pagina) {

        AcervoService service = retrofit.create(AcervoService.class);
        Call<UltimosLancados> ultimosLancadosCall = service.obterAcervo(pagina);

        ultimosLancadosCall.enqueue(new Callback<UltimosLancados>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UltimosLancados> call, Response<UltimosLancados> response) {
                aptoCarregar = true;
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    UltimosLancados ultimosLancados = response.body();
                    final ArrayList<Lancamentos> listaAcervo = ultimosLancados.getDados();

                    //progressBar2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(getActivity(), recyclerView, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                            Lancamentos p = listaAcervo.get(position);
                            String aString = Integer.toString(p.getId());
                            int aInt = Integer.parseInt(aString);

                            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), PerfilActivity.class);
                            i.putExtra("ID", aInt);
                            startActivity(i);

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                        }
                    }));

                    acervoAdaptador.adicionarItem(listaAcervo);

                } else {
                    Log.e("TAG", "onResponse" + response.errorBody());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UltimosLancados> call, Throwable t) {
                aptoCarregar = true;
                Log.e("TAG", "onFailure" + t.getMessage());

            }
        });

    }

}
```

```html
07-26 20:02:29.382 21112-21112/site.exemplo.project E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
07-26 20:02:29.382 21112-21112/site.exemplo.project E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
07-26 20:02:29.392 21112-21112/site.exemplo.project E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 45, size is 40
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
        at site.exemplo.project.AcervoFragment$2$1.onItemClick(AcervoFragment.java:108)
        at site.exemplo.project.RecyclerItemClickListener.onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerItemClickListener.java:26)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchOnItemTouch(RecyclerView.java:2916)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onTouchEvent(RecyclerView.java:3044)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8808)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2569)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2239)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2581)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2581)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2581)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2581)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2581)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2581)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2581)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2581)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2581)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2607)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1779)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2846)
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2568)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9003)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4209)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4072)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3627)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3680)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3646)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3763)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3654)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3820)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3627)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3680)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3646)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3654)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3627)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5910)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5884)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5855)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6000)
     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEven
```

Comment: Try debugging and see why it is  throwing the index out of bounds exception. Plus look at why your code is looking at index 45 when the size is just 40

Comment: Yes. For I am doing a pagination, but when I select it it does not find the position.

Comment: Have you looked and debugged what is going on at line 108 of AcervoFragment.java?